# Help with understanding why "のか" is used in this sentence

Tags: grammar, translation

I read this sentence:

"私はなぜ彼がこれをしているのか、分からない"

The sentence is supposed to mean "I don't understand why he is doing this," and I think it is grammatically correct since I found it in a japanese site ( but if it is not, please help with correcting it  ? ). My question is, why is のか used in this sentence? When is のか　used? I know how to use のが and のは、but のか looks new to me. Can it be replaced by のが？　(　私は彼がこれをしているのが、分からない　).

Comment: Not exactly duplicate because the given link above does not explain the compound particle のか.

Comment: Snail plane's answer there covers のか. [This question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3442/5010) would help, too.